# jQuery mobile inserting anchor tags in my li elements

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm just starting with jQuery Mobile and adapting an existing application.

My problem is jQuery mobile is inserting anchor tags in my li tags within an unordered list.

The doc tells me that read-only lists will be created if the list has no links.

This is very unexpected behavior to put it mildly.

When I comment out the JQM includes I get my simple li elements back, so I know it is JQM that is doing it.

Markup without JQM:

```
<ul id="root_ul" data-role="listview">

<li id="1_1306901436141">Profile
</li>
</li>
```

Markup after JQM:

```
<ul id="root_ul" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
<li id="1_1306901436141">

<div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
  <div class="ui-btn-text">
    <a href="#/evaluation_headers/714%20/tastesheet&amp;ui-page=ul1_1306901436141" >  <span>Profile</span>                    
  </a>

</div><span>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
</li>
```

JQM has put in links into the list but I want a simple readonly list with no links.

Comment: Hi mate! Could you provide some code?

Comment: Can't you just load your data to an array, sonrt an array and then put it somewhere on your website?

Comment: What version of JQM are using? Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ugerun/1/) using your markup and as you can see there are no extra anchor tags inserted.

Comment: JQM isnt to blame here, your list formats fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/7ynrc/    How are you initialising your listview?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for responding. In my effort to simplify my code to submit to this site I failed to include a nested list within an item. I created a simple nested list and found that this causes JQM to insert the links. Not what I want or expected but will now figure out a workaround. The nested lists are at the heart of my app so maybe I won't use JQM.

Thanks again for your responses.

Comment: You can try wrapping your nested `ul`'s in a div, that should prevent the links from being inserted.

Comment: Glad to help, I converted my comment to an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do do avoid jQuery Mobile inserting anchor tags for your nested `ul` is to wrap the nested `ul` in a `div`.  In fact besides for the conventions provided by the JQM framework you can also pretty much style a JQM `li` anyway you wish by placing what ever markup/css you want inside the `li`.

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>
        <div><ul>
                 <li>Sub List Item 1</li>
                 <li>Sub List Item 2</li>
        </ul></div>
     </li>
</ul>
```